# MediaInfo Fourcc Values

Tags: video, codec, quicktime

I'm trying to figure out what fourcc value I need to use but I'm a bit confused between file formats and codecs. 
I have a .mov file and MediaInfo reports it as shown below

I need to specify the fourcc value but can't see it explicitly listed. Is it the Color Space and Chroma subsampling values?
If it is the text I'm using suggests I call the file a .avi but does it matter if I call it a .mov?

```
Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L4.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 2 frames
Format settings, GOP                     : M=2, N=5
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 1h 8mn
Source duration                          : 1h 8mn
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 3 224 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 768 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 024 pixels
Height                                   : 576 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 1.942
Original display aspect ratio            : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 25.000 fps
Minimum frame rate                       : 3.125 fps
Maximum frame rate                       : 25.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.219
Stream size                              : 1.53 GiB (100%)
Source stream size                       : 1.54 GiB (100%)
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-01-16 15:40:20
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-03-09 18:41:42
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.601 PAL
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.601
```

Answer (score 1):

FourCCs are Microsoft's ID tags for **streams** e.g. `avc1` for H.264/AVC or `mp4a` for an AAC audio stream. The container doesn't really matter.

If you want to change the FourCC, use ffmpeg like so

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -strict -2 -c copy -vtag ABCD new.mov
```

where `ABCD` is your new 4CC/tag.

You current file already shows `avc1` for the video stream, which is default and expected.

Comment: I'm not looking to change the fourcc I actually want to know for sure I use the right value when I pass them as a argument to an OpenCV VideoWriter function call to split the original file into smaller segments. Does .avi or .mov matter if I have the fourcc set correctly?

Comment: Ah, don't know about OpenCV but there's broadly two steps involved - calling a demuxer so that OpenCV can locate and extract the video track. FourCC isn't involved here. And once the video track is being read, calling a H.264 bitstream reader/decoder to correctly split the video - FourCC is required to call the correct library or module. `avc1` is good for the 2nd part. Don't know OpenCV, so can't help with first. Maybe, based on extension, it auto-selects?

Comment: Found this property value in OpenCV `current_vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC) `which might do the trick for me but